# SELECT some distinct columns

Tags: mysql, select

Here's some test data.

```
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
| id | type | param | enabled | account | 
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
|  1 | test |     a |       1 |    null |
|  2 | asdf |     b |       1 |    null |
|  3 | test |     c |       1 |      34 |
|  4 | test |     d |       0 |      34 |
|  5 | asdf |     e |       1 |    null |
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
```

I want to SELECT the latest rows, where the "type" and "account" are unique.

For example, for that test table, I'd want the result:

```
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
| id | type | param | enabled | account | 
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
|  1 | test |     a |       1 |    null |
|  4 | test |     d |       0 |      34 |
|  5 | asdf |     e |       1 |    null |
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
```

I've tried variations of GROUP BY:

```
SELECT * FROM test GROUP BY type, account
```

For some reason that gives me this:

```
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
| id | type | param | enabled | account | 
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
|  1 | test |     a |       1 |    null |
|  4 | test |     d |       1 |      34 | <- note that enabled is taking on an incorrect value.
|  5 | asdf |     e |       1 |    null |
+----+------+-------+---------+---------+
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM test`?

Comment: DISTINCT applies to all of the columns selected. So in that example it'd select where 'id', 'type', 'param', 'enabled' and 'account' are all unique. I only want 'type' and 'account' to be unique.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your query is giving you the correct IDs, you should try putting it into a sub query:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM test GROUP BY type, account)
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. returns all rows.  see solution below

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that "latest row" means the one with the largest `id`, then there are several methods.  The method that uses `in` is:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE t.id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM test t2 GROUP BY type, account)
```